# Averaging probabilities predicted from two logistic regreesion models for multi class classification

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics

The data have 4 outcome classes, 1, 2, 3, 4. (1 is worst outcome, 4 is best outcome)

There are two logistic regression models proposed:

Model A: classify group 1+2+3 vs 4

Model B: classify group 1+2 vs 3+4.

Then for each individual, the predicted probabilities from the two models are averaged.

The questions are:

1) How to interpret the averaged value?

2) What does this value classify for?

3) Can we use this value find cutoffs to assign the indivuals to one of the 4 classes? (Based on sensitivity/specificity from the ROC curve).

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Why are you averaging the two probablities? From what I can tell, the result has no sensible interpretation.